# Positioning icon half above layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Recently, designers in my company liked creating half-above elements in layouts for Android apps. I've been struggling for a while trying to make these elements behave as good as possible, but I'm already tired of it. Is there any way of positioning views like on this image

[image: Layout]
with an assumption that if user touch row/card it became "checked" and this black dot icon became visible (second click makes it invisible of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circle_view"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/second_view"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout

    <View
        android:id="@+id/circle_view"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

second_view is endOf circle_view so if circle_view is gone second_view will align to startOf parent.

circle_view should have marginEnd set to negative value of its width divided by two

[image]

Comment: But i need "second_view" to always take full available space, I can't just make it 100dp width.

Comment: So set second_view width to match_parent :) I set 100dp only for test. I added screenshot how it look likes in editor

Comment: Working, but for some reason "second_view" is covering circle. Half of it is invisible. "second_view" is card view, and "circle_view" is imageview. I guess i should set elevation, but how to do this on API <19 ?

Comment: you can solve the issue by wrapping the CardView inside another FrameLayout. I updated my answer

Comment: Hate all these elevation issues on Android. Such a simple and popular thing, so many problems anyway.